# How to create circular progress bars for resume in Ms word

Tags: information-graphics, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I recently came across a resume template which had circular progress bars as such-

[image: sample]

Is there a way to recreate this in word?

Comment: Word is not a "drawing" application. Typically one creates such things in some other app, then imports images into Word. -- Sidebar.. such "progress" visuals mean *nothing*. 68% of what? All known knowledge? 68% compared to the last office staff? 68% of all application features. They may *look* interesting, but really just come across as "filler".

Comment: @Scott I don't necessarily mean to import percentages but I found the idea interesting to mention how confident you are in the particular subject. I will be using it for highlighting my proficiency in coding languages.
Could you please suggest which other app I can use to achieve this.

Comment: @SilianRail - almost any vector image editor would work.  Adobe Illustrator, Affinity Designer, Inkscape (free), CorelDraw, Figma etc.

Answer (score 1):

In word document
Insert Shape > Basic Shapes > select Block Arc
Draw a Gray arc and on top of it draw another orange arc and align.

Check the attached photo.

[image]

[image]